# xgboost and gridsearchcv in python

Tags: python, boosting

I have question about this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrJP9FLV3FE).

The author is doing hyper parameter tuning. The first window shows different values of hyperparameters

[image]

Then he initializes `gridsearchcv` and mentions `cv=3`
[image]

then he fits `gridsearchcv` and uses `eval_set`
[image]

what is the purpose using `cv` and `eval_set` both? shouldn't we use just one of them? what purpose does it serve by feeding both of them?

Answer (score 1):

Something is weird here.

`GridSearchCV` is used to find optimal parameters.  For every pair of parameters in the Cartesian product of `param_grid`, we fit `cv` models and average their performance.

The `eval_set` argument in XGboost seems to be evaluating the model on the passed data.  IF this was the test set, this doesn't seem to be appropriate because, if I have understood correctly, each model will predict on this test set.

The only rationale I can think of is as follows:  So long as the model is chosen from the results of the cross validation, and the `eval_metric` is passed only as a convenience (to have immediately after the cross validation and not to use for model selection purposes), then all is fine.  Typically tho, we would just pass the test set once to the selected model, rather than have the test set predictions on all models fit in the cross validation step.

Comment: the way I was thinking is that - `roc_auc` is used to find the best parameters and then `auc` and `test data` is used for early stopping. could that be it? seems confusing. what would be the best way to do final model? should i drop `eval_metric` and `eval_set` from `optimal_params.fit`?